# How to get child by its position?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Firebase with RecyclerView,I'd like to retrieve the child with a specific position to delete it. I know that I should use a query of `orderBy`, but I need to get a specific child by its position.

Is there a way to do this? I only found a way to get the number of children with `getChildrenCount()` method of the snapshot, but didn't find something by passing the position value.

Thank you.

```
    protected void populateViewHolder(final ReportViewHolder viewHolder, final Report report, int position) {

            viewHolder.txtTitle.setText(report.title);
            viewHolder.txtMessage.setText(report.message);
            viewHolder.txtDate.setText(report.date);
            viewHolder.txtuserName.setText(report.userName);

            viewHolder.btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    String key = report.key;

                    Query myTopPostsQuery = mDatabaseReference.child("user-reports/"+userID).orderByKey().equalTo(report.key);
                    myTopPostsQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                snapshot.getRef().removeValue();
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
                    mDatabaseReference.child("reports/"+ key).removeValue();
                }
            });

        }
    };
```

I want to use the position of `populateViewHolder`, to get the child position and then delete its node. 
Now I added a field for report called key and using `orderByKey().equalTo(report.key);` to delete it.

Comment: `adapter.getRef(position)` will give you the DatabaseReference for the item in a specific position. If you're having problems making it work, share the [minimal code that reproduces your problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add delete and add methods to your adapter class.

```
public class AllAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

List<Article> articleList = new ArrayList<>();
Context context;
public AllAdapter(Context context){
    this.context = context;
}

public void addItem(Article article){
    articleList.add(article);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void deleteItem(int position){
    articleList.remove(position);
    notiftyDateSetChanged(position);
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.view_post_item,null);
    return new ArticleViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return articleList.size();
}

class ArticleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public ArticleViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

    }
}
```

}